# How to add ZedGraph Control to Toolbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, zedgraph

I added zedgraph.dll to my wpf application. There after i add that control to my toolbox. But it is not add to my toolbox in wpf application. But it add in WinForm Application. Anybody have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. xmlns:zed="clr-namespace:ZedGraph;assembly=ZedGraph"
2. Add **WindowsFormsIntegration** to your references
3. Add this for example..:

   ```
   <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" Margin="500,0,0,0">

   <zed:ZedGraphControl x:Name="graph"
                                Width="500"
                                Height="320" />
   </WindowsFormsHost>
   ```

see
http://sourceforge.net/p/zedgraph/discussion/392231/thread/86678940/